# RDP starts minimized and cannot be switched to

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Windows7 SP1 x32 Professional in domain.
User can start RDP, type in password and clicks connect. RDP programs goes to taskbar, it looks like it's minimized and I can't bring it back.

I tried:

- restart the computer (of course)
- in Task Manager use *Bring To Front*
- start MSTSC /v:*MyServer* /f
- apply this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2939180/en-us)

And of course it's been working properly earlier. User is connecting to the terminal server, Windows Server 2012 R2. Other users can connect to this terminal.

Comment: Whenever I've had problems with MSTSC I replace the file. Go to another machine Win7 SP1 windows\system32 grab the MSTSC file and replace it on problematic PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some kind of conflict with smart card (bank token) used to sign up banking transactions. Removing it from USB port fixed everything immediately.